# How to get Code coverage using Robotium in Android studio?

Tags: android, code-coverage, robotium

In my project, i am using robotium as the testing framework,.
Now my requirement is ti find the code coverage using the same.
I am new to this so can you please help me with this.
Anybody has tried or know about this will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Jacoco can get Code Coverage and branch Coverage.Android Studio 2.0 has integrated Jacoco.
First,open build.grade

Add code given below in buildTypes.

```
 debug {
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }
```

Then sync your build.grade

click on Grade on right side of Android Studio.Click On your project.Then click on Tasks->other->right click on createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport->Run....
The test report will be in your project->build->reports->coverage->debug->index.html